# Hosting Web data in different location

Tags: server, apache2

I have practically run out of space in my root filesystem - just 60 Gb free, although it puzzles me why all my /media is included in that statistic. I have an Apache web server on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine and wish to either use a symbolic link or Virtual Host to point to another drive which has ample space.

I tried ln -s   but Apache complains about it and I get "Forbidden" when I try to see that directory from my browser. The log entry says:
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/fg

I tried doing as described here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html
to no avail. Also there seems to be a permissions problem and I cannot change the symbolic link permissions/owner from root to www-data.

I have sifted through many answers on this site but none seems to work.

I would value suggestions. I have astutely partitioned my drive so I cannot enlarge the root partition but have oodles of space in /home and on other drives. I was even thinking of using a SATA SSD to host this data but that won't work unless I can solve the problem above.

Comment: Have you configured AppArmor to allow Apache to access that other location?

Comment: No. I did not try that, but I was using Nautilus to allow sharing of those directories. The Apache log was still reporting errors such as: access to <> denied (filesystem path '/whatever) because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: I have no experience with AppArmor at all. It is installed on my desktop and I have just enabled it for Apache. So far I have not found anything to help me configure it to do that.